# Why this nginx rewrite rule add trailing slash?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I've the following rewrite rule on location /, and it enforces trailing slash!

```
location / {
        rewrite ^(\/.*) https://example.com/ar$1 permanent;
}
```

each, time I curl mydomain.com, I got the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://example.com/ar/
```

I do not want the trailing slash at the end of the redirected URL!

Comment: A url always _starts_ with / so `$1` will also with the config in the question.

Comment: Thank you, but any link/resource for that?

Comment: Look at the location block. You are matching a `/` and then inside the block too, you are matching a `/`. If you need to eliminate `/`, you need to ignore it somewhere. Probably, you are looking for the following solution... `location / { rewrite ^/?(.*) https://example.com/ar$1 permanent; }`.

Comment: @Pothi This one worked! Thank you, can you add it as answer?

Comment: Sure. Glad to know it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the location block. You are matching a `/` and then inside the block too, you are matching a `/`. If you need to eliminate `/`, you need to ignore it somewhere. Probably, you are looking for the following solution...

```
location / { rewrite ^/?(.*) https://example.com/ar$1 permanent; }.
```